# Unable to download youtube videos from shutil Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, shutil

I want to download a YouTube video using `Python`. I use this code to scrape images and it worked fine. But when i changed this image link to youtube video then it saves the file, but makes an error corrupted mp4 file. 
Any idea what i am doing wrong?

**Here's my code :**

```
import requests
import shutil
import time
import urllib

video_url = r"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hoNb6HuNmU0/hq720.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEZCNAFEJQDSFXyq4qpAwsIARUAAIhCGAFwAQ==&rs=AOn4CLBTdEdTL4oiRB_L8AJITd9xzfllMA"
resp = requests.get(video_url, stream=True)
local_file = open(r'C:/users/intel/desktop/local_image.mp4', 'wb')
resp.raw.decode_content = True
shutil.copyfileobj(resp.raw, local_file)
del resp
```

Any of your help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Your approach won't work.

Check https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl for the proper way to download YouTube videos.